# How does one \ref and \cite paragraphs in a mathematical text? (see picture)

Tags: math-mode, citing

How does one `\ref` and `\cite` partly mathematical "textblocks" that are in separated paragraphs?

Very good example here:  [A Short Proof of Fleischner's Theorem](https://www.google.fi/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://www.math.tugraz.at/~agelos/shortFleischner.pdf&ei=c-_rUMjmFceM4gSSg4CgDw&usg=AFQjCNGkPRFi0_v6pc62-BIhV7BJITtPVQ&sig2=sVsjfloQYgEYaAhYvtFUsA&bvm=bv.1357316858,d.bGE), **page 4**;
there are textblocks (1) and (2) and they are referenced several times in the latter text.

Here is a pic of the desired result:

[image: Example]

Comment: Aren't this textblocks lemas or theorems? You could use the `theorem` package to define lemas, assertions, ...

Comment: They are used exactly like \begin{equation}, so that you get a (number) in the margin. Then you can cite the (number) in latter text. 

If I use {equation}, I get lots of errors or one really long line of \text{...}

How do I get it to look like equation and have no errors? And be able to cite with a (number)?

Comment: @zunbeltz Do you mean \usepackage{amsthm}? It has theorems and I use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an `equation` environment with an embedded `array` whose only column is in paragraph format.  For example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\noindent
following assertion holds:
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:test}
  \begin{array}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
    for any \( i,j \), if \( v = x^i_j \) then all passes of \( J' \)
    through are marked except for the pass containing \( e^i_j \).
  \end{array}
\end{equation}
This is easy to verify\dots

So we assume that (\ref{eq:test}) holds\dots
\end{document}
```

This way you have the usual control that you are used to from equations.  Feel free to adjust the width of the paragraph.  I have chosen `0.8\textwidth`.  Some dimension is required.

The above solution may be packaged up into a dedicated environment as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{assertion}{\begin{equation}\begin{array}{p{0.8\textwidth}}}{%
  \end{array}\end{equation}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
following assertion holds:
\begin{assertion}
  \label{eq:test}
    for any \( i,j \), if \( v = x^i_j \) then all passes of \( J' \)
    through are marked except for the pass containing \( e^i_j \).
\end{assertion}
This is easy to verify\dots

\end{document}
```